# Getting a JSON and adding it to an array

Tags: json, angular

I have following JSON file:

```js
{
  "fruites": [
          {"id" :"f1", "name": "apple", "selected": "false"},
          {"id": "f2" , "name":"orange", "selected": "false"}
          ]
}


Here is my JSON interface:
export interface FruitsType {

  id: String;
  name: String;
  selected : String;
}
```

Not sure if this is a correct an interface.

I WANT TO USE THE NAME OF THE FRUITES AS VALUE FOR A CHECKBOX

To read this JSON I have following service:

```js
getJSON (): Observable<JSON> {
    return this.http.get<JSON>((this.configUrl))
  }
}
```

In my component I have follwowing code to read the get the JSON file:

```js
this.jsonService.getJSON().subscribe(response => {


     console.log(response.fruites);
      console.log(response.fruites[1].name);
      console.log(response.fruites.length);

      for (this.i = 0; this.i < response.fruites.length; this.i++) {


          console.log("id" + response.fruites[this.i  ].id);
          console.log("name" + response.fruites[this.i].name);
          console.log("selected" + response.fruites[this.i].selected);


        }

})
```

in the browser I can see that it works, while in the consule where i am running the ng serve I see the following error:

src/app/componenets/home/home.component.ts(221,41): error TS2339: Property 'fruites' does not exist on type 'JSON'.

The other thing is that I cannot push this to an array, I use the follwoing code:

```js
this.jsonArray.push(response.fruites[this.i].name )

AND

this.jsonArray.push(response.fruites)

AND

this.jsonArray.push(response)
```

All returs eithr undefined or nothing at all!

Please consult me on these.

Comment: post your JSON class/interface

Comment: Are you getting the response as expected? Inside the subscibe method?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I did now. if that is what you meant

Comment: as the error says you are returning a type of JSON which does not have fruits

Comment: yes. as  following:
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: "f1", name: "apple", selected: "false"}
1: {id: "f2", name: "orange", selected: "false"}
length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
orange
2
id: f1
 name: apple
 selected: false
 id: f2
 name: orange
 selected: false

Comment: maybe related, but surely solving your next question: `this.i` is introducing many possible bugs. You'd use a local variable for keeping track of current iteration. The sane syntax is `let i`

Comment: @Sajeetharan: yes, but I have never called or used that interface.

Comment: @baao: yes, strange enough I cannot introduce the i in the array itself as I have seen in the example, or even inside the function where I have the loop

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, sorry. It's impossible that you can't change `for (this.i = 0; this.i < response.fruites.length; this.i++) {` to `for (let i = 0; i < response.fruites.length; i++) {`

Comment: Guys, where I should have used that misspelled interface! I have never used it

Comment: @baao:oops you are right, I missed using "let"
I am quite new to both java scripts and angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the payload you are getting can be easily done as:

```
this.jsonService.getJSON().subscribe(response => {
        for(const i of response.fruites) {    // Iterate over the list
           console.log('Data set coming as - ', i);
           console.log('ID - ', i.id);
           console.log('Name - ', i.name);
           console.log('Selected - ', i.selected);
        }
array=[]; var item;
response.fruites.map((item) =>{  array.push(item.name)});
console.log('Array with name', array);`
```

Comment: hey. Thanks, that works. Can you help me adding it to an array? cuz I need to use these json as values for my checkbox

Comment: use a class with same properties as that in response.fruites. Make an instance of that class and you are good to go. Use arrName.push()

Comment: @ Aditya Goswami thanks for your replies. so i have a class as follows:
export  class Fruitrs{
  id: string;
  name: string;
  selected : string;
}
then I have an array : jsonArray : Fruitrs[];
then I do 

This.jsonArray.push(i.name) 
which gives me an error on push. How can I access the properties of the array to assign specific value of the JSON?

Comment: I have used map here. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
response.json().fruites
```

or

```
response.data.fruites
```

Answer (score 0):

in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50853473/3075338) , I have posted the full answer of how I got everything done which also relates to this question I have asked.